# How to develop a constexpr implementation of boost::pfr::for_each?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

I am using `boost::pfr` and it's quite impressive the way it uses reflection without any neccesity of macro registering of variables.

But the issue I wonder is why `boost::pfr::for_each` was not declared as constexpr, avoiding in current situation the use of PFR `for_each` within any constexpr function declared by users.

Is there any way I can bypass this issue without changing original boost::pfr source code?

EDIT: I include a working example and a link to coliru to show my point.

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/443f8bd2ad66ca4c

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/pfr.hpp"

struct Variable
{
};

struct Var1 : public Variable
{
   static constexpr int size { 5 };
};

struct Var2 : public Variable
{
   static constexpr int size { 10 };
};

struct Var3//This one does not depend of class Variable!
{
   static constexpr int size { 20 }; 
};

struct Packet
{
    Var1 var1;
    Var2 var2;
    Var3 var3;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr int accumulate(const T& ref) {
    int result{};
    boost::pfr::for_each_field(ref, [&](auto& field) { if (std::is_base_of<Variable, std::decay_t<decltype(field)>>::value) result += field.size; });
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    Packet packet;
    /*constexpr*/ auto size = accumulate(packet);//constexpr must be commented!
    std::cout << size;
    //static_assert(size == 15);//It can not be used due to non-constexpr!
}
```

Comment: Not sure why. It shouldn't be hard to implement on top of the basic tuple-like API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an oversight in the implementation, given that it could easily be constexpr, at least for the C++17 implementation - [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/W9EcYGY15)

In the meantime you can build your own constexpr one using `boost::pfr::structure_tie` (which is constexpr) & `std::apply`:

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/qWhesvMWo)

```cpp
template<class T, class F>
constexpr void for_each_field(T&& obj, F&& func) {
    std::apply([f = std::forward<F>(func)](auto&&... elements) mutable {
        (std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<decltype(elements)>(elements)), ...);
    }, boost::pfr::structure_tie(std::forward<T>(obj)));
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but while in gcc your solution is working fine, in MS VS2017 I got next errors (see comment below). Any idea why?

Comment: 1>c:\vc\pfr\prueba.cpp(47): error C2131: la expresión no se evaluó como una constante1>c:\vc\pfr\prueba.cpp(8): note: el error se debió a una llamada de función no definida o una 'constexpr' no declarada
1>c:\vc\pfr\prueba.cpp(8): note: consulte el uso de 'for_each_field::<lambda_c7a3e2c40dec474b823c61f2d831699a>::<lambda_c7a3e2c40dec474b823c61f2d831699a>'

Comment: @Pablo older versions of msvc seem to have a problem with mutable constexpr lambdas, capturing by reference fixes it: [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/43ohMYE99) (v19.16). Newer versions of msvc don't have this problem ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Eo5jYshqe)) (v19.30)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have learnt a lot of all this issue due to your explanations.